# Column header direction is SSRS Matrix

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

Hi is it possible to change the direction of column header values ?
By default header valules displayed in horizontal direction only. But I want to show the values in vertical direction. Is it possible?

I tried from the last 3 days. But no where I got any good results.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SSRS are you using? As far as I know, you can only change the orientation of the text in chart axes (at least in 2005).

Comment: 2008. But I want to apply orientation for Matrix not for charts. Is it possible?

Comment: Apparently not - I use SSRS 2005, but according to this posting MSDN it's not supported in SSRS 2008 either:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vsreportcontrols/thread/95155a7f-932d-4974-9133-87877b204351

Comment: Although this posting seems to indicate it should be implemented in SSRS 2008 R2:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/42299d7c-af6c-48b4-98b4-ad9d36f16290